# Spark Scala script to read data from S3 on daily basis

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, rdd

There is one java application which dump data(in csv file) to s3 on daily basis. This application create folder in S3 based on system date like(MM-DD-YYYY format) and then add files to the folder created.

Now i want to read those files from S3 on daily basis like

```
val fileFromS3= sc.textFile("s3a://digital/MM-DD-YYYY/abc.csv")
```

Now the script should replace **'MM-DD-YYYY'** with the **system date.**

Please suggest possible solution or any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get currentTime with Calendar class.

First you need some imports:

```
import java.util.Calendar
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
```

Then you can get the current Time:

```
val now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```

And prepare the formatter the retrieve the date in the proper format you want and to ensure double digit month and days

```
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Then you can use your formatter to get the date as String

```
val dateAsString = formatter.format(now)
```

Then you can load your resource with the `dateAsString` value using [String interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html):

**edit to remove typo:**

```
val fileFromS3= sc.textFile(s"s3a://digital/${dateAsString}/abc.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks @SCouto for your quick resolution.

Everything is working fine, except dateAsString variable id not getting resolved while reading file. Getting 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException:' ,Do we missing anything here.

Comment: Oh sorry, i have a typo. I'll fix it in the answer

Comment: That's it, you need an 's' before the String to use String interpolation and resolve the variable

Comment: Wow, thats working fine now. Thank you so much for sharing doc link on 'String interpolation'.